# subset xts with object in R

Tags: r, xts

There has to be a simple solution for this, but somehow I can not find it. I would like to subset an xts object by year (easy), but by using another object.

```
data <- xts(1:1000, Sys.Date()+1:1000)
data['2016',]  # this will give all 2016 data
```

Now I would like to do this:

```
year <- as.numeric(2016)
data['year',]
```

Obviously that does not work. Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You need a `character` object:

```
year <- "2016"
data[year]
```